# Setting a Role-Based Access Programmatically

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have developed an app on Android that uses the Firebase realtime database. aka multiple nodes in the DB store various data collected by my app. For Auth, email/password-based Sign-in and Sign-up are working properly. When I sign-up a new user the auth works but that new user then needs to be granted access to the firebase database nodes the app uses. My app needs to grant this new user access to the firebase database nodes required for app interaction.

In other words, how do I programmatically, via my app, change the firebase node-access/security rules in my app (when I currently only know how to change these via the Firebase browser UI)? I do not see methods in FirebaseAuth to do this. So, where do I go from here?

Also, obviously a new user of my app will not have my credentials but they must be able to add access for themselves to my existing firebase realtime database nodes. How do I this?

Here are the rules I have in place today (where my UID is my actual firebase UID):

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid === my UID",
    ".write": "auth.uid === my UID"
  }
}
```

I now understand I must set rules to allow all authenticated users to read write data in various nodes of my tree. I do not yet understand how to grant access by node and particularly by a specific uid-based node in a tree where there may be many UIDs for each user. As an example, if my tree is root (top), then messages, then a UID for each user, what is the syntax for an authorization rule that will allow the current user/UID read/write the data in only his/her UID under root, messages, his/her user UID?

Comment: What rules do you have right now?

Comment: Thanks - I edited my post above to share what my current rules are. I have been watching this  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUBnlbjZFAI